# How to move all the file of same type to single folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to move the `.txt` files from all the folders or subfolders to one single folder.

what I have tried is this:

```
import shutil
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.move(file,'dest')#print (file)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test - Copy (2).txt' -> 'dest'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 552, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test - Copy (2).txt'
```

Kindly, let me know how to resolve this and successfully move or cut past al my files from the folder and sub-folders having extension `.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're just passing the file name to `shutil`, instead of the full path. You can use `os.path.join()` in order to join the base path with file name:

```
import shutil
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file),'dest')
```

If you want to replace all the files within the destination directory, you need to pass the full path of file names or just remove all the files within the directory.

Also instead of using `os.walk()` as a more pythonic way for finding files with a specific format you can use `glob()` module.

Comment: sorry, but where the files went? I do not see the dest foolder anywhere

Comment: @JafferWilson Is the `dest` name of a folder? I think it should exist already before you move your files.

Comment: And if there are file with same name it gives error.

Comment: @JafferWilson I think in case of replacing a file you need the full path of all your files not only the directory.